# PHP Yii2 framework run multiple websites using single core code and one server

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Is it possible with Yii2, I can run multiple websites using single core code and one server?
Suppose I have 5+ websites , each website has own database, theme is same for all, only single server on backend, but I'm not sure how I can achieve this goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible - in fact Advanced Template Project is built like this.
Each website is single app so instead of having `frontend`, `backend` and `common` you can have something like `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`, `ddd`, `eee` being the names of the websites. Each app can get its own configuration.

There are obvious limits to this implementation:

- `vendor` folder is the same for every app so every app gets the same packages in the same versions no matter if required or not,
- server must be able to handle more requests at the same time.

Comment: It means if I have a change for all sites then I should update into `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`, `ddd`, and `eee`?

Comment: The names can be whatever you want. Remember to set aliases for new apps like in [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/config/bootstrap.php)